# is it possible to call one static block from another

Tags: blocks, static-block

I want to ask a very basic question. 
Is it possible to call one static block from within another using

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}
```

or can you only do this from a cms page?

i did this and my site now wont connect, but i don't see any errors. then my host said at the same time as i was doing this they had a problem with the upstream provider. but now i can barely connect or do anything on the backend of the site.

yet other sites on our server are moving fine. any thoughts?

Comment: Please consider XML layout update instead.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server provider issues. I do not think adding a cms block would cause issues not being able to access the Magento Admin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to nest CMS blocks like you describe.
The syntax you are using is exactly right. The issues you where experiencing must have been something else.
Just try again and it will work, as long as you don't create a recursive inclusion loop.